# Time machine: include external FAT drive

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, fat32, guid

I am trying to backup an external FAT drive with time machine on a new WD HFS+ formatted hard drive, and I've read it is possible.

However, I find it in the **excluded** list, and I cannot remove it since it is grayed out.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Your FAT drive needs to be formatted using GPT[GUID] (or GPT+MBR which is how Boot Camp does it, but it's not necessary for a regular, data only, non-Windows OS disk) rather than 'plain' MBR.

There are two utilities I know of which can change the underlying format from GUID to MBR without destroying the data - [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com/iPartition/) & the new [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/).
Of the two, right now Paragon looks the most future-proof, iPartition hasn't seen an update in a while & cannot handle CoreStorage volumes.

*Not an advert, no affiliation, I'm not providing links you'll have to Google it*
Right now, summer 2016, Paragon HDM is $40 but there's a company called BundleHunt - kind of a 'Groupon' for Mac apps - who are doing it in a bundle of any 7 apps for $16. The resultant version you get registers properly with Paragon as though you'd bought it direct.

Failing that, you would need to wipe & reformat the drive in Disk Utility - which cannot do the 'soft' conversion.
It *might* be possible to do from terminal, but that's beyond my pay-grade, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @tetsujin, I have a concern about this: will Windows OSs mount the drive after the switch to GPT? This is a critical point, if XP won't mount it, then I might be unable to change the partition.

Comment: XP 64 & up can read GPT disks, but not XP32.

Comment: @Tetsujin What about GPT+MBR (GPT with a protective MBR)?